Crop & Zoom Videos Without Quality Loss - iOS Swift
I have been spending time trying to figure out how to crop and zoom a specific video based on user input from a scrollview.
Imagine we have a zoomable view (works for images and videos). This includes a scrollview and an av player layer. Users can zoom and pan around within the view which will be cropped later.
I am able to calculate the crop area and reposition the video within a mutable composition, however I can't seem to "fit" the video within the render size without losing quality.
Basically, I want screenshot 2 to fill the render size in screenshot 3 but look like screenshot 1.
Below is the code I am currently using with a few screenshots.
Note: Please ignore the quality of the screenshots, I had to convert to jpeg to get them to upload on SO.
if let videoMutableTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {
        do {
            try videoMutableTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: fileAsset.duration), of: videoTrack, at: .zero)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
            self.setErrorInfo(error)
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }
        
        if (fileAsset.duration > maxDuration) {
            maxDuration = fileAsset.duration
        }
        
        let size = videoMutableTrack.naturalSize.applying(videoMutableTrack.preferredTransform)
        
        var scaleRatioX = (renderSize.width / 2) / size.width
        var scaleRatioY = (renderSize.height) / size.height
        if (rotate) {
            scaleRatioX = (renderSize.width) / size.width
            scaleRatioY = (renderSize.height / 2) / size.height
        }
        
        var scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatioX, y: scaleRatioY)
        
        let offsetX = -currentVideoView.contentOffset.x
        let offsetY = -currentVideoView.contentOffset.y
        
        let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoMutableTrack)
        if (videoFile.fileId == 1) {
            var move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            
            if (shouldUseDefaultScaling(currentVideoView)) {
                scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatioX * (currentVideoView.zoomScale / 2), y: scaleRatioY * (currentVideoView.zoomScale / 2))
                move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offsetX, y: offsetY)
            }
            
            layerInstruction.setTransform(move.concatenating(scale), at: .zero)
        }
        else {
            var move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: size.width, y: 0)
            if (rotate) {
                move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: size.height)
            }
            
            if (shouldUseDefaultScaling(currentVideoView)) {
                scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleRatioX * currentVideoView.zoomScale, y: scaleRatioY * currentVideoView.zoomScale)
                move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: offsetX, y: offsetY)
            }
            
            layerInstruction.setTransform(move.concatenating(scale), at: .zero)
        }
        
        compositionInstruction.layerInstructions.append(layerInstruction)
    }

let currentFrameRate = Int(roundf((videoTrack.nominalFrameRate)))
    highestFrameRate = (currentFrameRate > highestFrameRate) ? currentFrameRate : highestFrameRate
    
    compositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: maxDuration)
    
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: renderSize)
    
    let mutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.instructions = [compositionInstruction]
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(highestFrameRate))
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = renderSize
    mutableVideoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: outputLayer)




